# React get props from Router with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm **trying** to refactor my code using `React Hooks`, and I don't really understand how I can get props passed down to my components via React Routers using Hooks.

The old (normal) React code looks like this:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from './routes/Routes';

function App() {
    const childProps={something: "else"};
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Routes childProps={childProps} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Routes.js

```
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Game from '../game/Game';
import Scenario from '../game/Scenario';

const CustomRoute = ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) =>
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
            <C {...props} {...cProps} />
        }
    />;

export const Routes = ({childProps}) => 
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Game} props={childProps} />
        <CustomRoute path="/scenario/:id" exact component={Scenario} props={childProps}/>
    </Switch>
```

Game.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Game = () => {
  return (
    <div className="Game">
      <header className="Game-header">
        <a href="/scenario/0">
          START
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Scenario.js

```
export default class Scenario extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            scenarios: null,
            scenarioId: null,
            currentScenario: null
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const scenarioId = await this.props.match.params.id;
        const scenarios = await data.scenarios;
        this.setState({scenarios, scenarioId});
        this.getScenario();
    }

    getScenario = () => {
        this.state.scenarios.forEach((scenario) => {
            if (scenario.id === this.state.scenarioId) {
                const currentScenario = scenario;
                this.setState({currentScenario});
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.currentScenario != null
                    ? this.state.currentScenario.options.length === 1
                        ? (
                            <div>
                                <div>{this.state.currentScenario.text}</div>
                                <div>{this.state.currentScenario.options[0].text}</div>
                                <a href="/">Go Back</a>
                            </div>
                        )
                        : (
                            <div>
                                <div>{this.state.currentScenario.text}</div>
                                <div>{this.state.currentScenario.options.map((option, index) => (
                                    <div key={index}>
                                        <a href={`/scenario/${option.to}`}>
                                            {option.text}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                ))}</div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    : null
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

So I found online this code which would change the way I can get props from the Router:

HookRouter.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const RouterContext = React.createContext(null);

export const HookedBrowserRouter = ({ children }) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route>
      {(routeProps) => (
        <RouterContext.Provider value={routeProps}>
          {children}
        </RouterContext.Provider>
      )}
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export function useRouter() {
  return React.useContext(RouterContext);
};
```

New App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {Routes} from './routes/Routes';
import {HookedBrowserRouter, useRouter} from './routes/HookRouter';

function App() {
    const childProps={something: "else"};
    return (
        <HookedBrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
            <Routes childProps={childProps} />
        </div>
        </HookedBrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

And I get his far with the new Scenario.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import data from '../data/fake';
import {useRouter} from '../routes/HookRouter';

const RouterContext = React.createContext(null);

const HookSceneario = () => {
    const [scenarios, setScenarios] = useState(null);
    const [scenarioId, setScenarioId] = useState(null);
    const [currentScenario, setCurrentScenario] = useState(null);

    // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
        // Update the document title using the browser API
        // console.log(React.useContext(RouterContext));

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(scenarios);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            // ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

So `useState` replaces the `this.state` inside the class constructor, and `useEffect` is supposed to replace `componentDidMount` but I can't find a way to get the `props` from the Router.

Comment: Do you need `routeProps` in a child of `<Scenario/>`? Because the way you're doing it, as Scenario is being rendered by the `<Route>` component and you're passing down the `routeProps` in `render={(routeProps) => <C {...routeProps)/>`. Note that I've renamed to `routeProps` to make clear that the `props` object available in the `render` prop ARE the `routeProps` (match, location, and history). Therefore `<Scenario/>` already has access the the `routeProps`.

Comment: Thank you @cbdev420 for your suggestion. So you're the one who wrote that block of code. My question is how do I call those props inside `Scenario` as a function with Hooks. It doesn't seem like I can `console.log` any of the props like with a class.

Comment: i think async lifecycle method is bad ideaa... i can make separate async function and move this logic there. then you call this function inside componentdidmount like  getScenarion

Comment: @Bonjov Thank you for your suggestion. Unless I misunderstood your comment, it seems like the code above does what you suggest: calling an async function inside componentDidMount.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this illustrates well what you're trying to do:

Remember:

The component rendered by a `<Route>` can always have access to the `routeProps` (match, location and history).

If it's rendered by the `component` prop, as in `<Route ... component={Home}/>` this is automatic.

If it's rendered by the `render` prop, you need to spread them, as in:

```
// You can spread routeProps to make them available to your rendered Component
const FadingRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => (
    <FadeIn>
      <Component {...routeProps}/>
    </FadeIn>
  )}/>
)
```

[Link on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/userouterhookso-s9j8h)

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

**Full Code:**

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AllRoutes from "./AllRoutes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AllRoutes />
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**AllRoutes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Component1 from "./Component1";

function AllRoutes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/comp1" component={Component1} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default AllRoutes;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      I am HOME component
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={"/comp1"}>Component1</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      I have access to routeProps: YES
      <br />
      Because I'm directly rendered from a Route
      <ul>
        <li>{"props.match:" + props.match.toString()}</li>
        <li>{"props.location:" + props.location.toString()}</li>
        <li>{"props.history:" + props.history.toString()}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Component1.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Component1Child from "./Component1Child";
import RouterContext from "./RouterContext";

function Component1(props) {
  const routeProps = {
    match: props.match,
    history: props.history,
    location: props.location
  };

  return (
    <RouterContext.Provider value={routeProps}>
      <div>
        <b>I am Component1</b>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        I have access to routeProps: YES
        <br />
        Because I'm directly rendered from a Route.
        <br />
        And I automatically 'inherit' them when I'm rendered through the Route
        'component' prop
        <ul>
          <li>{"props.match:" + props.match.toString()}</li>
          <li>{"props.location:" + props.location.toString()}</li>
          <li>{"props.history:" + props.history.toString()}</li>
        </ul>
        <Component1Child />
      </div>
    </RouterContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Component1;
```

**Component1Child.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Component1GrandChild from "./Component1GrandChild";

function Component1Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <b>I am Component1Child</b> <br />
      <br />
      I have access to routeProps: NO
      <br />
      Because I'm NOT directly rendered from a Route.
      <br />I am rendered by Componen1 and routeProps are not automatically
      passed down.
      <ul>
        <li>{"props.match:" + props.match}</li>
        <li>{"props.location:" + props.location}</li>
        <li>{"props.history:" + props.history}</li>
      </ul>
      <Component1GrandChild />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component1Child;
```

**Component1GrandChild.js**

```
import React from "react";
import useRouteProps from "./useRouteProps";

function Component1GrandChild(props) {
  const [match, location, history] = useRouteProps();
  return (
    <div>
      <b>I am Component1GrandChild</b> <br />
      <br />
      I have access to routeProps: YES
      <br />
      Because I'm consuming the routeProps provided by Component1 (which is the
      one directly rendered by the Route)
      <br /> And I'm consuming that through a custom hook called useRouteProps.
      <br />I am rendered by Componen1 and routeProps are not automatically
      passed down.
      <ul>
        <li>{"props.match:" + match}</li>
        <li>{"props.location:" + location}</li>
        <li>{"props.history:" + history}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component1GrandChild;
```

**RouterContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

const RouterContext = React.createContext(null);

export default RouterContext;
```

**useRouteProps.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import RouterContext from "./RouterContext";

function useRouteProps() {
  const routeProps = useContext(RouterContext);
  return [routeProps.match, routeProps.location, routeProps.history];
}

export default useRouteProps;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Please let me implement your code and get back to you (marking this as correct).